# RxJs - Redux-Observable Navigate after Action Fulfilled

Tags: rxjs, navigation, redux-observable

This is more a code review request than an actual question.

I have this code below that redirects the user if the authentication completed correctly and i would like to know if this is a good|correct|optimal way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

```
  const loginEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(LOGIN_USER),
    mergeMap(action =>
      ajax({
        url: `${BASE_URL}/auth/login`,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: action.payload
      }).pipe(
        map(response => loginUserFulfilled(response)),
        takeUntil(
          action$.pipe(
            ofType(LOGIN_USER_FULFILLED),
            mapTo(history.push("/stuff"))
          )
        ),
        catchError(error =>
          of({
            type: LOGIN_USER_REJECTED,
            payload: error.xhr.response,
            error: true
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: How do you emit LOGIN_USER_FULFILLED ?

Comment: from the loginUserFulfilled action. this is how things are done in redux-observable. What actually worries me is the part inside the takeUntil operator and the actual usage of this operator

Comment: It looks strange indeed because `ajax` emits once and then completes. There's no actual need in `takeUntil`. Does `history.push("/stuff")` return and action object?

Comment: `history.push("/stuff")` does the actual redirect, so the logic is that if the login action is fullfilled without errors move to `/stuff` route. But I am in the process of learning `rxjs` so i don't know if this is an optimal approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`takeUntil` operator completes an observable as soon as the provided observable completes. Since `ajax()` observable emits once, there is no need in `takeUntil`.

Redirection is a side-effect. It's recommended do side effects in `tap` operator.

It also often makes sense to provide the redirect side-effect in an appropriate epic:

```js
import { tap, ignoreElements } from "rxjs/operators";

const loginEpic = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(LOGIN_USER),
        mergeMap(action =>
            ajax({
                url: `${BASE_URL}/auth/login`,
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                body: action.payload
            }).pipe(
                map(response => loginUserFulfilled(response)),
                catchError(error =>
                    of({
                        type: LOGIN_USER_REJECTED,
                        payload: error.xhr.response,
                        error: true
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    );

const loginRedirectEpic = action$ =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType(LOGIN_USER_FULFILLED),
        tap(() => history.push("/stuff")),
        ignoreElements(),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @sneas, i will check it out as soon as i can.

Comment: it keeps redirecting me to the `/stuff` route. i'll try to debug it

Comment: sorry, made a mistake in the `tap`. You got to pass callback. Fixed it.

Comment: where does `history.push` come from in your example? `react-route-dom`?

Comment: Daniel, reach-router